# Law of Demeter - why do I need to use a getter?

Tags: java, list, law-of-demeter

I have a question regarding the Law of Demeter in relation to Lists contained within other objects in Java. I have the following class.

```
public class Conversation
{
    Person person;
    List<Message> conversationList;

    public List<Message> getConversationList()
    {
        return conversationList;
    }
}
```

To add a new Message object to conversationList in this class I would typically do something like the following.

```
Conversationc = new Conversation();
c.getConversationList().add(new Message());
```

After a bit of reading this would appear to violate the Law of Demeter and adding a method to Converstaion like the following, would be "better" way to approach this.

```
public List<Message> addMessageToList(Message msg)
{
    conversationList.add(msg);
}
```

However this seems like complete overkill to me. What is the best practice approach in this this situation?

Comment: I would use the second approach. The signature should be `public void addMessage(Message msg)`.

Comment: The second one provides better abstraction and readability (you should seriously consider @LutzHorn's suggestion  ... This is what you would want as a programmer using an OO language.

Comment: @TheLostMind Right, and even with a merely modular language :-)

Comment: Also if you are worried about good practices: your list of message is named conversation list and the class is spelled wrong, twice, which seems like it is like that in the actual code.

Comment: One additional word (to the already good comments and answers): Consider the design! You would like to have a conversation that consists of messages. With the public getter for the list you designed a conversation that has a list which consists of messages. See the difference?

Comment: But let's say you would have to use multiple methods of the list, like.. add,remove,sort,etc.. would you encapsulate them all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However this seems like complete overkill to me.

Ahh I remember asking myself this question repeatedly when I was first starting out  - when the word *encapsulation* was something I had learned for a test but didn't really understand the "necessity" of.

I say that because *encapsulation* is what we're talking about here - a one-word answer to your question:

Accessing `conversationList` through a [getter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html) - which is what the second pattern you've posted here is called - *encapsulates* your list of conversations in your conversation class. It's hard to see why this is important when the programs you're writing have three or four classes tops and have requirements that are both simple and fixed: When you're still wrapping your head around how these small programs work, this whole notion of "adding a getter" rather than accessing fields directly seems like just one more thing to do, one more you thing you don't really understand *why* you have to do, and one more place you can muck something up.

That feeling, of course, will go away as you get more confident, and something else that will happen is you'll start thinking about and working on applications that are much larger and more complex, and whose requirements will change (both in reality and in the perception of them) over time, and this will often mean your programs need to change - and that's when encapsulation will start to make an awful lot of sense:

For now: Pretend that your teacher changes this assignment he's given you tomorrow, adding an unforeseen requirement to this program you've been working on (which, incidentally, I think would be a smart thing for teachers to do). Imagine that the only way you can meet that requirement is to keep your list of conversations in a `Map` instead of a `List`, so you can map each of them to some other value.

If you've been using "your first approach" - calling `conversationsList.add()` to access that field directly in many different classes, you'll then have to go through and change every one of those classes to call `conversations.put()` instead of `.add()`.

But if you've been using the second approach - accessing your collection through a getter - then you can change that collection however significantly you need to and you'll only have to make one change - to that getter:

```
 public void addMessageToList(Message msg)
{
    this.myMessagesManager.put(msg, new ArrayList<SomeValue>);
    //or .put(msg, null) or whatever
}
```

Your other classes will never know anything changed, which is great because it means you write less code, and *particularly* great because it keeps you from having to do a lot of *the worst kind of coding* - with all the pulling-of-hair and gnashing-of-teeth that's often involved in catching bugs that arise from little mistakes you make when you're making one of these little changes to one of those classes.

(also, see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23420403/return-print-field-value-or-just-print-value-through-class-method/23420566#23420566) for a better illustration)

Comment: Good answer. So if I wanted to introduce a getMessageList() method that returns the list of messages. Should I make this returned list immutable so it can't be modified outside the Conversation class? Or should I do something different here?

Comment: [Immutability](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html) and [access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) are two very different things. Encapsulating something doesn't mean making it immutable, it means preventing other classes from *accessing* it (directly), which we do by putting access modifiers such as `private` or `protected` on it. You should check out those two links, especially the latter.

Comment: So if I'm not "allowed" to access the list directly then any get methods for my object should also be wrapped like the add method?

Answer (score 0):

With the first approach, you cannot change the implementation of `conversationList`.

Imagine that you decide to use a whole new class to take care of the messages, let's says `MessagesManager`, then you have to change every call in every class that thought it was a `List`.

But with `public void addMessage(Message msg);`, then you can use

```
public void addMessageToList(Message msg)
{
    this.myMessagesManager.addMesasge(msg);
}
```

You have encapsulated your data model, `Conversation` does what it wants with its `Messages`, no one else will care.

Comment: I agree with you .To keep the addMessage interface stable, neither we should use [conversationList.add] nor [conversationMap.put], but we can delegate this to a MessageManager class, which manage the message.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of roles and responsibilities.
In the first approach that Role takes on the responsibility of adding a message to the conversationList, but it should really be the responsibility of the Conversation objects.
In the second approach you delegate that responsibility to the Conversation object.
You tell the Conversation object to store a Message and that's it, you don't care how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of both. The name of method should represent the action that wold be performed on object instance.

In your case of conversation method starting with `add` is kind of ambiguous. So the question is what is the further action with that message.

The conversation has two aspects, you can listen or speak.

`converstion.listen(Message)` or `conversation.listenMessage(Message)`

When you design an API (public method) try to use it and see that it behaviour is.

```
conversation.listen(whatTomSad());
vs
conversation.listenMessage(whatTomSad());
```

At this level is quite hard to decide. I would select the first one. Because it give flexibility and proper API abstraction as well.

Lest assume that our API will grow and will hat to server not only `Message`.

In case of solution we only overload the method, and leave the API quite extend but we do not force user to adopt. He can easily change the return type of his method.

```
conversation.listen(whatTomSad());
conversation.listen(whatTomSing())
vs
conversation.listenMessage(whatTomSad());
conversation.listenSong(whatTomSad();
```

To simplify and conclude. The method name should be not only depend on the object but on the context it would be used by its user of API (developer). It should have attributes like:
 - self expression 
 - not surprising
 - easy to refactor

To balance that is quite complicated. Best way to learn it. Observe the code of other developers and learn form their mistakes.